Finding a cycle on $m$ vertices with minimum weight on a weighted complete graph on $n$ vertices.
Given an edge-weighted complete graph $K_n$, what are some possible approaches/techniques/methods or algorithms for determining:
A cycle (with start and end vertex $v^*$) on $m$ vertices  ($m<n$) in $K_n$ with a minimum weight?
Thank you so much for your help.

It sounds very similar to traveling salesman problem (which it would be if $m=n$). I would start by looking at (approximation) algorithms for that. If $m$ is allowed to vary, you basically have a longest path problem (looking for the longest closed path from $v^$ to $v^$).

I totally agree @MatthewSpam for the $m=n$ case. I just would like to ask further regarding "you basically have a longest path problem (looking for the longest closed path from ∗ to ∗)"? What I want actually is the shortest cycle length involving $m$ vertices. Thank you very much.

This is the problem I was referring to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Thank you @MatthewSpam.

Unfortunately, even in the very special case when $m=n$ and each edge-weight is $0$ or $1$, the problem is equivalent to the Hamiltonian cycle problem, which is NP-hard. Therefore the expected algorithms have to be rather slow.
I can propose the following simple algorithm.
Let $V$ be the set of the vertices of the given graph, $U\subset V\setminus \{v^*\}$, $|U|\le m-2$, $v\in V\setminus (U\cup\{v^*\})$, and $w(U,v)$ be the weight of a minimum weight path $p(U,v)$ from $v^*$ to $v$ through all vertices of $U$. Then $w(\varnothing,v)$ is the weight $w(v^*v)$ of the edge $v^*v$ and $p(\varnothing,v)$ is $(v^*,v)$. We can calculate the remaining values $w(U,v)$ recursively with respect to $|U|$, extending the paths $p(U,v)$ accordingly. Namely, if $U\ne\varnothing$ then
$$w(U,v)=\min_{u\in U} w(U\setminus\{u\},u)+w(uv).$$
Moreover, if the minimum is attained at a vertex $u\in U$ then let $p(U,v)$ be the path $p(U,u)$ extended by the edge $uv$. Finally it remains to pick a pair $(W,v)$ minimizing the value of $w(U,v)+w(vv^*)$ when $|U|=m-2$. Then the required cycle is the path $p(W,v)$ closed by the edge $vv^*$.
